# One dimentional random walk

Tags: combinatorics

I need to calculate the number of such trajectories of length $n$ (started at $0$ and end at $a$), that for giving $k$ substitute following rule: the maximum isn't greater than $a$, and for every interval of length $k$ exists such a point, at which the value of the trajectory is equal or greater than at the beginning of that interval. For the last interval the maximum should be $a$.

I've tried to get the recurrent for that value. $H_na = H_(n-1)(a-1) + H_(n-2)a$. It's very strange that it doesn't depend on $k$. I don't know how to calculate that in other way or how to solve the recurrent.